# Take string from brackets and put into an array to organize

Tags: jquery, arrays, timer, split

I'm trying to build a timer where I'll display the most recent update based on a string entered by a user.

An example string:

```
var text = "Shawn [Samson] arriving on [3/28/18 5:43 PM]";
```

So I am trying to extract any info surrounded by brackets, storing it into an array and then finding the closest time and display that in a timer.

How I'm trying to get the string in the bracket:

```
var abc = text.slice(text.indexOf('[') +1,text.indexOf(']'));
```

But it's only returning `a`

An example of what I would put in the form to pull from:

```
Shawn [Samson] arriving on [3/28/18 5:43 PM]
Shawn [Jones] arriving on [3/29/18 5:43 AM]
Shawn [Simms] arriving on [3/28/18 5:43 PM]
Shawn [Samson] arriving on [3/28/18 10:43 PM]
```

Comment: _But it's only returning `a`_, not for me it isn't. It returns `Samson` as expected

Comment: yes, @MattBurland returning Samson

Comment: Hmm odd. I will check.

Comment: @MattBurland Thanks, I found why that portion wasn't working. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To process a single string:

```js
    var text = "Shawn [Samson] arriving on [3/28/18 5:43 PM]";
    var regex = /\[([^\]]+)\]/g;
    var tmp;
    
    do{
        tmp = regex.exec(text);
        if(tmp){
            console.log(tmp[1]);
        }
    }while(tmp);
```

Iterating over an array of strings and storing data:

```js
var texts = [
    "Shawn [Samson] arriving on [3/28/18 5:43 PM]",
    "Shawn [Jones] arriving on [3/29/18 5:43 AM]",
    "Shawn [Simms] arriving on [3/28/18 5:43 PM]",
    "Shawn [Samson] arriving on [3/28/18 10:43 PM]"
]
var results = [];
var regex = /\[([^\]]+)\]/g;
var tmp;
for(var i = 0, j = 0; i < texts.length; i++){
 results[j] = [];
 do{
  tmp = regex.exec(texts[i]);
  if(tmp){
   results[j].push(tmp[1]);
  }
 }while(tmp);
 j++;
}
console.log(results);
```

Edit: Solution for the comment below:

```js
var texts = "Shawn [Samson] arriving on [3/28/18 5:43 PM]Shawn [Jones] arriving on [3/29/18 5:43 AM]Shawn [Simms] arriving on [3/28/18 5:43 PM]Shawn [Samson] arriving on [3/28/18 10:43 PM]";

var results = [],
    regex = /\[([^\]]+)\]/g,
    i = 0, j = 0,
    tmp;

results[0] = [];
do{
    tmp = regex.exec(texts);
    if(tmp){
        results[j].push(tmp[1]);
    }
    if(i%2 != 0){
        j++;
        results[j] = [];
    }
    i++;
}while(tmp);
results.splice(-1,1);

console.log(results);
```

Comment: What if I was to get a block of text in one full string: `"Shawn [Samson] arriving on [3/28/18 5:43 PM]Shawn [Jones] arriving on [3/29/18 5:43 AM]Shawn [Simms] arriving on [3/28/18 5:43 PM]Shawn [Samson] arriving on [3/28/18 10:43 PM]"` How would I approach it to separate it like you did in the second code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the desired result.

```js
var str = "Shawn [Samson] arriving on [3/28/18 5:43 PM]",
capturedData = (/.+(\[.+\]).+(\[.+\])/).exec(str).slice(1, 3);
console.log(capturedData);
```